# Cleaner way to pass multiple variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing the following variables in a json structure to my backend:

```
<a href="#;" class="match-item"

   data-reviewqueueid="{{ item.pk }}"
   data-useremail="{{ user.email}}"
   data-instanceid="{{ item.item_id }}"
   data-tracktitleid="{{ item.tracktitle_id }}"

   data-contenttype="{{ search_item.content_type_id }}"
   data-titleimdbid="{{ search_item.imdb_id }}"
   data-tvseriesimdbid="{{ search_item.imdb_series_id|default:'' }}"
   data-titlename="{{ search_item.name }}"
   data-titlereleaseyear="{{ search_item.release_year }}"
   data-ispartoftitle=""
   data-shouldbetvseries=""
   data-matchedfromimdb="{% if search_item.imdb_id and search_item.content_type_id != 'TV Series' %}true{% else %}{% endif %}"
   data-tvseriesname="{{ search_item.imdb_series.name }}"
   data-collectionepisodenumber=""
   data-collectionseasonnumber=""
   data-tvseriesreleaseyear=""
   data-collectionname="">
    Match
</a>
```

And in the javascript:

```
var data = new Object();

data.TVSeriesReleaseYear = $(this).data('tvseriesreleaseyear') || null;
data.CollectionName = $(this).data('collectionname') || null;
# ... etc ...
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)

$.post('{% url submit %}', jsonData, function () {
    ...
});
```

Each "item" is a search result object. Is there a clearer way to pass this data to the backend, or is this the suggested way?

Comment: You could just fetch all the data attributes on the element with `var data = $(this).data();`, that way you don't have to manually type out all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data()` with no arguments to get all data attributes combined as one object

```js
console.log($('a.match-item').data())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#;" class="match-item"
   data-reviewqueueid="1"
   data-useremail="foo@bar.com"
   data-instanceid="2"
   data-tracktitleid="3"
   data-null="null"
   data-true="true"
>
    Match
</a>
```

Comment: I think most browsers suppose [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) these days, so maybe no jQuery is needed.

Comment: @MarkMeyer right but since it appears OP using jQuery already just went with that

Comment: @charlietfl -- thanks, is there a way to specify a `null` or `true/false` value in the data-value? Or do I need to post-process the data?

Comment: See edit with attributes `data-null` and `data-true`. Could also use `$.extend()` to merge with defaults if needed

Comment: @charlietfl wouldn't `null` be picked up as the string `"null"` instead of the type `null`? Or does the above work with the correct type?

Comment: Yes is correct type in javascript and would also be correct in JSON...in other words would not have quotes as shown in the console log

Comment: Note if you send as json need to set proper `Content-Type` header in request